# UK immigrant visa appeal status check

Tags: united-kingdom, application-status

One of my cousins applied for an immigration visa for his spouse. The application was refused and he filed an appeal. It has been more then 1 year since he filed the appeal; is there any way to track the appeal status?

Answer (score 2):

Without pertinent details, it is difficult to know where to direct you to check on the status of the appeal.

To enquire about an appeal, or for more information about the appeals system, contact:

[First-tier Tribunal (Immigration and Asylum Chamber)](https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/first-tier-tribunal-immigration-and-asylum)
PO Box 6987
Leicester
LE1 6ZX
Email: customer.service@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk
Telephone: +44 (0) 300 123 1711

Note that during the initial appeals process, roughly between 30-90 working days after filing, your cousin would have been given official written notice whether the appeal would be heard, by what court or tribunal, where and when. That should give you what you need to [locate that court/tribunal](https://courttribunalfinder.service.gov.uk/search/) and address your enquiry directly to it.

Comment: i really appreciate you took time to answer my question, Yes he got the hearing appointment, went on hearing but they said we will write a letter and inform you with our decision, its been 4 weeks did not heard back from them.

Comment: @Nestsouls but that's progress and 4 weeks is acceptable; he may have to wait another 4-8 weeks. It's difficult, but try not to stress. Buona fortuna.